# Publish Test Results step fails on "No Result Found to Publish", but JUnit file is present

Tags: azure-devops, postman-collection-runner, postman-newman

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that runs some Postman tests with newman, then publishes the test results to a JUnit XML file. I have this step:

[image]

Followed by this step (all other steps have been disabled):

[image]

However, when running the pipeline I get this error. Note line 10:

[image]

But as shown here, the file exists in that location:

[image]

What is going on? Why can't Azure Devops find the file?

Comment: Can you check if test_results.xml is not empty and has a correct JUnit scheme?

Comment: And check if any failed tests are in tests_results.xml file.

Comment: Found it! Thanks Kontekst. One test was throwing an error due to a bad URL, causing the Publish Test Result task to fail.